# MUI: how to style a <p> using sx prop?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

When using MUI v5's styling system, when you write

```
<Box sx={{
    p : {
        marginBottom: '6px'
    }
}}> 
    <p>My Text</p> </Box>
```

Then that doesn't translate to `<p>` elements having a margin-bottom, because `p`is used as a shorthand for `padding`, see here: https://mui.com/system/properties/#legend

So how am I supposed to style a paragraph? Is targeting using classes the only option here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to do something like this

```
<Box sx={{
 '& > p': {
          marginBottom: '6px'
        }
 
}}> 
    <p>My Text</p> 
</Box>
```

Comment: thats smart!! thanks